# Show response from php in ajax

Tags: ajax

Here what I want to do..

1. Make a form using ajax to submit data.
2. Text typed by the user stored in a file
3. When the same user use the form again, the php file will check if the word exist in the log file. If exist, the ajax show error message.
4. If he enter new text, the form can be used..

Im trying to google, but I doesnt find any website that provide such tutorial..
For your information, Im new to jquery..

please help me to do as I mention above..